# I want to join two query from mysql, update by select?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT @mynumber := number
FROM tqueue
WHERE STATUS =  '4'
 AND get_ticket >= CURDATE( ) 
AND get_ticket < DATE_ADD( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 1 
DAY ) 
GROUP BY services
ORDER BY nomor ASC; 

UPDATE tqueue SET STATUS =  '8' WHERE number = @mynumber ;
```

My question is, can I join this select inside update query? Because I had problem with using multiquery in php?

this query updating status column look at my table

```
------------------------------------------
  number    |   status     |   get_ticket
------------------------------------------
    4              4          17:58:00 
    3              4          16:00:00
    2              4          13:05:13
    1              8          12:05:34
```

with using that query i can change the minimum number, will change from 4 to 8 status, when i update again min number with status 4 number 2 will change to 8, update again number 3 to 8 status and will continue like that, or if you have php code, can you give me sample code with php form my case, update from select

Comment: Yes you can join select query inside update query

Comment: Show the PHP/mysqli usage.

Answer (score 0):

Use first query as `subquery` for `where` condition.

```
UPDATE tqueue SET STATUS =  '8' WHERE number =(SELECT number
FROM tqueue
WHERE STATUS =  '4'
 AND get_ticket >= CURDATE( ) 
AND get_ticket < DATE_ADD( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 1 
DAY ) 
GROUP BY services
ORDER BY nomor ASC);
```

Comment: #1093 - You can't specify target table 'tqueue' for update in FROM clause